# Hooking into an update of the db system table

Tags: 7

Essentially I want to be able to monitor all updates to the db system table, by catching all updates to the db system table (for a particular theme's record). We have encountered some odd bugs whereby all themes are periodically (and apparently randomly) disabled, and I need to be able to log further information whenever this theme is disabled. What is the best way to approach this?

Alternatively is there a way to hook into the function for whenever a theme is enabled/disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`hook_themes_disabled()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_themes_disabled/7).

The following code in a module will put themes being disabled into the Drupal logs:

```
function MYMODULE_themes_disabled($theme_list) {
  foreach ($theme_list as $key => $themename) {   
    watchdog('MYMODULE', '%themename was disabled.', array('%themename' => $themename), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
  }
}
```

EDIT:  Forgot to mention this, but [`hook_themes_enabled()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_themes_enabled/7) is used in exactly the same way, so you could easily just modify the hook above to check when a theme is enabled.